# Connect to safari web inspector for debugging app on iPad over wifi

Tags: javascript, debugging, remote-debugging, web-frontend

Is it possible to debug a web app running on iPad from Safari in MAC by connecting both MAC and iPad to same Wifi network?

Comment: I use the Textastic editor app for debugging iOS,  it has a console and firebug and runs on ipads and phones, as for doing it over wifi I don't know

Answer (score 0):

The short response is "no". You need to plug the usb cable.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can. In my case, we have an ASP.NET MVC web application that was hosted in my local LAN network. I can debug and test the web application by Fiddler Web debugger and iPad iOS11 device. Therefore, I view my web application from iPad, then the Fiddler have all debug information. It's same thing for your scenarios.

How can I do that?

```
Step 1: Go to Fiddler options -> Connections: checked Allow remote computer to connect, and give fiddler listens on port: 8888 
Step 2: Go to your iPad and setup your network proxy to your machine.
```

Then you can debug now.